# regex all occurences of a string after Symbol =

Tags: regex, splunk

I try to match all occurences of a string after the specific symbol = and a whitespace

the regex i build is:

```
(?<=\=\s).*
```

my Data look like this:

```
$User = h03425
$test = some longer string in here
$input = 1243452
```

What i match with this regex is h03425.

To Use this regex reliable i need to match all values after = and a whitespace,
but since the amount of lines in the Data provided isn`t set, it could happen that there is only one line where it matches or up to 10.

And, i aint sure if thats possible, in the best possible way it would not involve Capture groups, but that is optional.

Comment: It [looks good](https://regex101.com/r/KhqFJv/1). Please show the code/explain how you are using the pattern. Also, please explain what the expected matches are for the given text samples.

Comment: I tried it with the /m flag and it would work, since i plan on using it in Splunk Software im not sure if i can use flags in it since it doesnt show me any matches at all when i write / before and /gm after my regex

Comment: No, you do not need `m` flag here since you are not using anchors. Since it is Splunk, try something like `|rex max_match=0 "=\s*(?<my_value>.*)"`

Comment: the max_match=0 helped, now it works with my lookup just fine, thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```
| rex max_match=0 "=\s*(?<my_value>.*)"
```

Here,

- `max_match=0` will extract all matches
- `=\s*(?<my_value>.*)` is the pattern with a named capturing group that is necessary to help Splunk extract a part of the text and assign it to the `my_value` variable that you can use/access later.